Dyalog APL: Is it possible to do inline text editing?
For Object class from Dyalog APL: How to write array of Objects to XML File?.
Is it possible to make a function that outputs the value of the Name field and allows you to edit it?
What do I mean by that:

Print _People.Name
Get user input, but don't newline (inline mode)

See image:

Edit the value of a variable (point 1), rather than typing from a new line (point 2).

I think what you're after is assignment to ⍞ followed by reading the value of ⍞. E.g.:
      var←'old value'
      ⍞←var ⋄ var←⍞

Here it is in action:

